# How can I have a foreign key that points to a computed column?

Tags: sql-server

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Question] (
    [QuestionId]       INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Text]             NVARCHAR (4000)  NULL,
    [QuestionUId]      UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
);
```

I would like to create a foreign key linking `QuestionUId` in my other table `AdminTestQuestion` back to the `QuestionUId` in the `Question` table.

> The referenced table '[dbo].[Question]' contains no primary or candidate keys that match the referencing column list in the foreign key. If the referenced column is a computed column, it should be persisted.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: As the error suggests you need to add a PRIMARY KEY Constraint in your parent table
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Question] (
    [QuestionId]       INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [Text]             NVARCHAR (4000)  NULL,
    [QuestionUId]      UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
);

Comment: Since this is really **NOT** a computed column (just a column with a default), all you need to do is make it either the primary key of the table, or at least you need a unique index on it (`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UIX_QuestionUid ON dbo.Question(QuestionUid)`)

Comment: @marc_s: short remark *not about the question*. [Your profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/13302/marc-s) contains two links in the text "Jon Skeet's helpful hints on how to write a good question (or at least his short version here)" which are broken. Fixed links seems be [this](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [this](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: @marc_s: Alternative place of the same URLs (because moving of the blog): [here](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [here](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) or short URLs: [here](http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints) and [here](http://tinyurl.com/stack-checklist)

Comment: @Oleg: thanks - updated my profile with the new links you provided!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: this is really **NOT** a computed column - it's just a regular column with a default constraint...

For a column in a table to be used for a foreign key reference, it must be either the **primary key** of that table, or it has to have a **unique index** on it.

So here, all you need to do is to add a unique index on your column

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UIX_QuestionUid ON dbo.Question(QuestionUid)
```

and then you should be able to reference it as a foreign key.